# telnet on a port and fire command from shell script

Tags: bash

My requirement is a script to telnet on a port and fire command.
I can manually do this from bash mode.
First of all i fire command "telnet 0 3300"
Then i get the prompt saying "Enter Command:"
So then i enter "LOGIN:sogadm:sogadm;"
So now i have logged in to that port.
After this i again get the prompt "Enter Command:".
SO now i can fire my specific commands.

Below i have shown the logs, how it goes on:

---

bash-3.00# telnet 0 3300
Trying 0.0.0.0...
Connected to 0.
Escape character is '^]'.
CONNECTING TO CAI...

PROCESS cai3300 CONNECTED...

Enter command: LOGIN:sogadm:sogadm;
RESP:0;
Enter command:   SET:AIRSUB:MSISDN,551100116:ACTIONTYPE,REFILL:REFILLPROFILEID,1:TRANSACTIONAMOUNT,500000:TRANSACTIONCURRENCY,DZD;
RESP:17200;
Enter command:

---

SO i want my script to do all this.
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The output you give, what application is that? Or did you dummy it up as an example of what you want a script to do?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking up expect and autoexpect. Expect is designed to control interactive programs such as the one you have (prompting for passwords, expecting commands ..). Autoexpect is a script that can generate the appropriate expect script from  a sample session.

Run something like:

```
autoexpect telnet 0 3300
```

and after you finish, the generated script will be in script.exp

This can be integrated in your script via a line like this:
   expect script.exp

Most of the content of script.exp it's comments, you can remove them and copy the script in your bash script and run it something  like this:

```
echo 'set timeout -1
spawn telnet 0 3300
expect "Enter command:"
send -- "LOGIN:sogadm:sogadm;"
expect "Enter command:"
send -- "SET:AIRSUB:MSISDN,551100116:ACTIONTYPE,REFILL:REFILLPROFILEID,1:TRANSACTIONAMOUNT,500000:TRANSACTIONCURRENCY,DZD;"' | expect
```

Note that the above is just an example, you should read the docs and adapt to your needs.

Alternatively, you can switch to perl and use Net::Telnet (I'm sure that Python has something similar if you are more comfortable with it)

Answer (score 0):

You want to [look up "here" documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).  Something like

```
telnet 0 3300 << EndOfTelnet
sogadm:sogadm;
0;
SET:AIRSUB:MSISDN,551100116:ACTIONTYPE,REFILL:REFILLPROFILEID,1:TRANSACTIONAMOUNT,500000:TRANSACTIONCURRENCY,DZD;
EndOfTelnet
```

Should do what you're asking.  Standard caveats about including passwords in scripts, etc.

Answer (score -1):

ssh, if you can use it, can make your life much easier.
You can just do "ssh -luser command". It will prompt for a password, so you'll have to feed it one.
There are some ways to avoid giving it the password. [this link](http://nosheep.net/story/password-less-ssh-login/) explains one way.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `nc` (netcat) command:

```
cat command_list | nc 0 3300
```

Where command_list is a file containing the list of commands to enter, one per line.

Note that this won't account for errors; ie, the password has changed, etc. It's a one-shot send each line of input in order.